# Facebook API's FB object null after init

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Facebook API's FB object just seems to go null after init. This is the code I'm using, it's quite simple. The problem is that it says my "/me" response is undefined. I'm logged in, just double checked, so this is not the case. I already gave it permission to use my data.

Why is my "/me" responce undefined?

Also, is there a way I can move my code:

```
function testAPI() {
                        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                        });
                    }

                    testAPI();
```

Into a separate .js file (with the code wrapped in a function), and have it load when function gets called inside window.fbAsyncInit? Cause every way  I've tried to do that resulted in failure.

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>FB-Stuff</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : '[my code]', // App ID
                  channelUrl : '//[my channel]', // Channel File
                  status     : true, // check login status
                  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
                });

                function testAPI() {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    });
                }

                testAPI();
            };

            // Load the SDK Asynchronously
            (function(d){
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            }(document));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit-------------------------------------------------------

Now I'm not getting any function calls/error messages at all. This is the new code:

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>FB-Stuff</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : 'xxx', // App ID
                  channelUrl : '//xxx/channel.html', // Channel File
                  status     : true, // check login status
                  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
                });

                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                  if (response.status === 'connected') {
                        facebookInit();
                    }
                });
            };

            // Load the SDK Asynchronously
            (function(d){
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            }(document));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And inside mycode.js is:

```
function facebookInit(){
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to defer the call to `FB.api` until *after* the status has been resolved - use `FB.getLoginStatus` or listen to one of the events for this.

Not sure what you mean with moving the code - you can put this code anywhere as long as it is loaded before the JS SDK.

Comment: Alright, I tried that (as seen in my latest question edit (Under the edit line) and it still didn't work.

Comment: Oh, god, I'm so retarded lol. I'll add your answer as the correct one asap. Oh, and thank you :)